# appending a counter to a string obtained by dereferencing macro variable

Tags: sas

how do I get so inside the loop I get: var1, var2? I know it does not work to dereference j but the meaning gets more clear to what I want to do (see below)

```
%let var1 = apple;
%let var2 = pear;


data _null_;
do j=1 to j=2;
put &var&j; //<---?
end;
run;
```

> in the log:
>
> ```
> apple
> pear
> ```

Comment: You don't have a macro variable J anywhere. A Do loop in a data step does not create macro variables. So explain a bit more what you're trying to do and we can recommend a better solution. Are you trying to use those values in  a data step, or would a macro loop replacement work, or do you not want to wrap the code in a macro? And your `DO` loop statement is incorrect, it should just be `do j=1 to 2;`.

Comment: I doubt that the log would actually output the text `apple` or `pear`.  Instead the data step should fail to compile and you should get warnings that the macro variables `VAR` and `J` are not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted above, J is not a macro variable so you cannot use it as such. You can use the SYMGET function to retrieve the value though. Assuming you want data step logic for some reason:

```
data _null_;
do i=1 to 2;
    x= symget(catt('var', i));
    put x;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to resolve a macro variable whose name you are creating by appending the value of another macro variable to some constant prefix.

If you try to use code like this:

```
%let var1 = apple;
%let var2 = pear;
%let j=1 ;
%put &var&j;
```

You will get an error message that the macro variable named `VAR` does not exist.

You need to  signal to the macro processor that it needs to delay trying to evaluate `&var` until after the suffix has been appended.  The way to do this is to double the first `&`.

```
%put &&var&j;
```

The presence of double `&`'s will cause the macro processor to replace them with a single `&` and set a reminder to itself the re-scan the result for more macro variable references.

So the first pass will replace `&&` with `&` and replace `&j` with `1`. Then the second pass will replace `&var1` with `apple`.